# Terminal on MacOS Mojave: Why is the prompt misbehaving when the window size is too small and how do I fix it?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, prompt

I'm on macOS Mojave 10.14.4 using GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1).
Basically my issue is that when the terminal window is too narrow to contain my full PS1 prompt in one line, it gets corrupted and starts duplicating over and over.

Here's a picture after I've made the window narrow and large again:

[image: insert picture of broken prompt]

I don't believe I've seen anyone report that issue on here but please feel free to tell me if this sounds familiar.

Here is the relevant part of my .bashrc:

```
#Colors in the terminal
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx

export PS1="\[$(tput bold)\]\[\033[38;5;36m\]\u\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]@\h:[\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;9m\]\W\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]]\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;226m\]\\$\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\] \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

I have tried this with different prompts that I'm certain were good with respect to the `\[` thing which was mentioned in various posts. The colors don't seem to be the problem either.

This is especially annoying as I am trying to use a window manager-type app (Amethyst) and that means my terminal windows are often made small, which triggers that behaviour.

I'll be grateful for any piece of advice. In the meantime I'll be looking at the GNU bash reference manual.

Comment: Guess: One of the invocations of `tput` fails for some reason, which causes a new prompt to be emitted, which then fails again ... What happens if you rewrite `PS1` to use the escape sequences from the `tput` commands directly, without using `tput`?

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for your guess. I tried setting `PS1="[\u@\h:\w]$\[\033[0m\] "` as well as `PS1="\u@\h $ "`, neither of which contain any instances of `tput` as far as I can see(?). Sadly, this does not solve the issue.